# Lifting the mond in conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit, http-conduit

I’m trying to consume an streamed http response. Problem is `httpSource` expects a `MonadResource` in the output conduit and I’m in `IO` so I figured I would get out a `ResourceT IO` :

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let c :: ConduitT () (Either String ServerEvent) (ResourceT IO) ()
      c = httpSource "http://localhost:3000/sse" $ toSrc . responseBody
  return ()
  where ...
```

Now I’m stuck with a `c` that is a conduit of `ResourceT IO` and about the only thing I can do is to `runResourceT` which I don't want. What I want is to get the same type but with IO :

```hs
ConduitT () (Either String ServerEvent) IO ()
```

I thought this must be easy but apparently not! best I could find was the https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.3.4.3/docs/Data-Conduit-Lift.html which as far as I can see is not relevant to my case (I could be wrong though).

Comment: What you're asking for is probably impossible (or "possible but impractical/pointless").  The *function* you're probably looking for is `transPipe`, and `transPipe runResourceT $ httpSource ...` will type check.  Unfortunately, it won't actually work as intended.  Perhaps you could explain *why* you can't run your whole computation in `ResourceT IO` (i.e., why not `main = runResourceT $ do ...`), and I could try to provide a more helpful answer.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr you are abs. right as I learned recently. How about you turn your comment into an answer, perhaps explaining why this is both impossible and not advisable. This way I can accept it as the answer and learn something as well :)